# $\lim_{x \to 1} \dfrac{\ln(x^2+1)-\ln(2)}{x-1} $

Tags: limits

$$lim_{x \to 1} \dfrac{ln(x^2+1)-ln(2)}{x-1} $$

I have tried doing this for an hour now, no clue what to do. My entire efforts have been directed as using the fact that $lim_{x \to 1} \dfrac{ln(x)}{x-1} = 1$, but I haven't been able to.

I have noticed that $x^2*1= (x-1)(x+1) + 2$, which might have to do with ln(2) being there.

Comment: Do you know l’Hospital’s rule?

Comment: Yes, my textbook hasn't introduced it yet so I don't think I am allowed to use it.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott That would be circular.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122: No, it would not.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Maybe circular is the wrong word, but using L'hopital's rule to evaluate $\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x - x_0}$, the definition of the derivative, seems fishy.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122: It shouldn’t. It’s *unnecessary*, but there’s absolutely nothing *fishy* about it once the necessary theorem has been proved.

Comment: Indeed, invoking LH to identify the limit of $(f(x)-f(1))/(x-1)$ when $x\to1$ is circular since LH requires to identify $f'(1)$, which is, *by definition of the derivative*, the required limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By setting $z=x-1$ and exploiting $\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\log(1+z)}{z}=1$ we have
$$ \lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\log(x^2+1)-\log(2)}{x-1}=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{1}{z}\log\left(1+\frac{z^2+2z}{2}\right) =\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{z^2+2z}{2z}=\color{red}{1}.$$

Comment: I don't understand how you rewrote the limit in terms of z

Comment: @Maximolian: by setting $z=x-1$, so $x-1$ turns into $z$, $\frac{x^2+1}{2}$ turns into $1+\frac{z^2+2z}{2}$ and $\lim_{x\to 1}$ turns into $\lim_{z\to 0}$.

Comment: @Maximolian: $\frac{1}{x-1}=\frac{1}{z}$ and $$\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\log\left(1+\frac{z^2+2z}{2}\right)}{\frac{z^2+2z}{2}}=1$$ by the initial lemma.

Answer (score 4):

**HINT:** Use the definition of a derivative on the function $f(x) = \ln(x^2 + 1)$. Namely:

$$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\ln(x^2+1) - \ln(2)}{x - 1} = f'(1)$$